# inserting data in foreign key table in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a table

```
tbl_group
----------
groupId    (pk)
groupName
```

and another table

```
tbl_group_head
--------------
groupHeadId (pk)
groupId     (fk)
designation
```

I have already inserted data in `tbl_group` like `1002,cs` and `1003,mca`.

How to insert in `tbl_group_head` in `joomla(2.5)`?

Comment: As @MarkoD said - make another query. Take a look at postSaveHook() function in JControllerForm - it allows child controller access to model data after the data has been saved.

Comment: how does your sql query look like?